# If $x, Tx$ is linearly dependent for all $x$, then $T=\lambda I$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

I was reading an argument where $V$ is a bijective bounded linear, or conjugate linear mapping on a Banach space $X$.
In order to show that $V = λI$, it shows that there is a contradiction if there exists $x\in X$ such that $x$ and $Vx$ are linearly independent. Why does this proof work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the proof, you get that $\{x, Vx\}$ is dependent for every $x \in X$.  For $x \neq 0$, this means that for every $x \in X$ there is a scalar $\lambda_x$ such that $Vx = \lambda_xx$.  So what remains to be shown is that $\lambda_x$ doesn't actually depend on $x$, since then we will have $Vx = \lambda x$ for all $x \in X$ and for that common value of $\lambda$, so $V = \lambda I$.

So suppose we have $x, y \in X$, both non-zero; our goal is to show $\lambda_x = \lambda_y$.

First, suppose that $x \in span(y)$, say $x = cy$. Then $$\lambda_xx = V(x) = V(cy) = cV(y) = c\lambda_yy = \lambda_y(cy) = \lambda_yx,$$ so since $x \neq 0$ we have $\lambda_x = \lambda_y$.

Now suppose that $x\not\in span(y)$.  Then we have
$$\lambda_{x+y}x + \lambda_{x+y}y = \lambda_{x+y}(x+y)=V(x+y) = Vx + Vy = \lambda_xx + \lambda_yy,$$
so $$(\lambda_{x+y}-\lambda_x)x = (\lambda_y-\lambda_{x+y})y.$$  Now since we are in the case $x \not\in span(y)$ this implies that $\lambda_{x+y}-\lambda_x = 0$, so $\lambda_x=\lambda_{x+y}$.  On the other hand, $y\neq 0$, so the left side being $0$ tells us that also $\lambda_y = \lambda_{x+y}$.  Therefore $\lambda_x = \lambda_{x+y} = \lambda_y$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm also confused about the symbol $Vect\{u,v\}$ ($u,v$ are any vectors). I've been searching the internet but I could't find any interpretation. Could you explain what it means?

Comment: Without context, I don't know either.  I don't think that is a standard notation.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{e_i\}_{i\in J}$ be a basis for $X$. Since $e_i$ and $Te_i$ are linearly dependent, $Te_i=\lambda_ie_i$ for some scalar $\lambda_i$, so the matrix corresponding to $T$ is diagonal. Suppose $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$ for some $i,j\in J$. Then the element $x=e_i+e_j$ satisfies $Tx=\lambda_ie_i+\lambda_je_j=\lambda_ix+(\lambda_j-\lambda_i)e_j$. Since $\lambda_i\neq\lambda_j$, we see that $x$ and $Tx$ are not linearly dependent. This is a contradiction, so we must have $\lambda_i=\lambda_j$ for all $i,j\in J$. Therefore $T=\lambda I$, where $\lambda$ is the common value of all the $\lambda_i$.

Answer (score 1):

This is a purely algebraic fact (the normed space structure is not needed at all). Assume $x$ and $Tx$ are linearly dependent for all $x\in X$. This means that for all $x\in X$ there exists some scalar $\lambda_x$ such that
$$
Tx = \lambda_x x.
$$
We show that for all non-zero $x,y\in X$ we have that $\lambda_x=\lambda_y$. There are two possibilities:

If $x$ and $y$ are linearly dependent. We can assume $y=\alpha x$ for some scalar $\alpha\neq 0$. Then
$$
\alpha\lambda_y x =\lambda_y y = Ty = T(\alpha x) = \alpha Tx = \alpha\lambda_x x 
$$
and since $x\neq 0$ and $\alpha\neq 0$ this implies that $\lambda_x = \lambda_y$.

If $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, then
$$
\lambda_{x+y}(x+y) = T(x+y) = Tx + Ty = \lambda_x x + \lambda_y y,
$$
and thus
$$
(\lambda_{x+y}-\lambda_x)x + (\lambda_{x+y}-\lambda_y) y= 0
$$
and since $x$ and $y$ are linearly independent, we conclude that
$$
\lambda_x = \lambda_{x+y} = \lambda_y.
$$

Thus $\lambda_x = \lambda$ for all non-zero $x\in X$, for some scalar $\lambda$. Then $Tx=\lambda x$ for all non-zero $x\in X$, but the equality is trivially true for $x=0$, so $T=\lambda I$.